# Array String outputs empty string (bug?)

Tags: java, arrays, string

**Here is my code:**

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = s.nextInt();
s.next();
String[] words = new String[n];

for ( int a = 0; a < n; a++ )
{
    words[a] = s.nextLine();
}  
for ( int a = 0; a < n; a++ )
{
    System.out.println(words[a]);
}
```

The program is about inputting a number of how many lines of string you will input.

Now when I input 2, the size of the words array will become 2, on the first for loop it will ask the user to enter a string N times. after that, the second for loop will print all the inputted words from the array, but it only outputs empty strings.

**Example of unexpected output:**

```
2
hello
world

Process completed
```

**Expected output:**

```
2
hello
world
hello
world

Process completed
```

i dont know why, but when i put some System.out.print() or System.out.println() in my program it works perfectly

Comment: What is `s`? You have several different methods on it, but no idea what they do.

Comment: @krillgar I would assume a `new Scanner(System.in)`.

Comment: What's the type of `s`?

Comment: What  exactly is `s` in your code? Can you post link to javadoc?

Comment: @toKrause my bad, but the thread has been edited

Comment: @assylias hello , about the duplicated topic, I have read it but i dont think we have a similar problem

Comment: @LorenceHernandez replace `s.next();` with `s.nextLine();` - I then get your expected output for the given input.

Comment: @LorenceHernandez You need to call `s.nextLine()` instead of `s.next()` after `s.nextInt()`.

Comment: When i do that and input 2 in nextInt(); the first forloop only enable me to input one string. its like after inputting the first string the loop skips the next words[a] = s.nextLine();

Comment: This is not a dublicate , really I cant understand those people , here is your code , u just mess up 1st line with the 2nd.My solution is another scanner instance.Power users have to understand that conversatios for the easiest thing and maybe dublicate some times help us all...   :(

Comment: package StackOverFlow;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author fotis
 */
public class arraay {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = s.nextInt();
String[] words = new String[n];
System.out.println("Please enter " + n + " words.");

for ( int a = 0; a < n; a++ )
{
    Scanner word=new Scanner(System.in);
    words[a] = word.nextLine();
}
System.out.println("your input is :");
for ( int i = 0; i< n; i++ )
{
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}
    }
}

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis i tried your code but when i input 2 and then input two words, hello world, the first output is hello and the 2nd output is empty string. and when i input 3 it only enables me to input 2 words. i dont know if my jcreator has a bug or my jdk

Comment: Works fine here.I paste again : package StackOverFlow;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author fotis
 */
public class arraay {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = s.nextInt();
String[] words = new String[n];
System.out.println("Please enter " + n + " words.");

for ( int a = 0; a < n; a++ )
{
    Scanner word=new Scanner(System.in);
    words[a] = word.nextLine();
}
System.out.println("your input is :");
for ( int i = 0; i< n; i++ )
{
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}
    }
}

Comment: thanks but its still the same.

Comment: It's astonish , they hold or put dublicate everywhere.Thats maybe because of comment text.Can you write an email for some seconds so i can send you the code?

Comment: i dont know why, but when i put some System.out.print() or System.out.println() in my program it works perfectly

Comment: I got it delete your mail

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LKBp66hq can you take a look at this? the snippets works differently when i put or remove line 29. i cant think of anything, is it really a bug?